# A vector in a function space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Suppose we let 
$$L^{p=2}(D,\mathbb{R})$$ denote a set of real functions on a domain D such that if $$\mathbf{a} \in L^{p=2}(D,\mathbb{R})$$
then we have 
$$\int_{D} \left | a(t) \right |^{2}dt<\infty$$

This is from my notes which leaves me very confused.

In the general case, the $$L^{p}-space$$ is defined as

$$\left \| f \right \|_{p}=(\int_{D}\left | f \right |^{p}d\mu )^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

In the case where p=2, the expression outlined in my notes appears to be suspect.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: The $L^p$ space is the space of (equivalence classes of) functions $f$ which satisfy $\int |f|^p < \infty$. What you have written down is the (semi-)norm on the space, not the space itself.

Comment: @Svetoslav Is my notes correct? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan So my notes are referring to the Norm?

Comment: To avoid confusion, It should be written like this:
In the general case, the $L^p$-space is defined as all Lebesgue-measurable functions $f$, for which $\int\limits_{D}{|f|^p d\mu} < \infty$.

Note that there is a little difference between $L^p$ and the calligraphic L$^p$. One is a linear space of equivalence classes and the other is the linear space of  measurable functions, as @PrahladVaidyanathan mentioned.

Comment: @Svetoslav I'm feeling more confused than ever. I have searched the web and none of the sources I came across had any definition similar to what was given on my notes.

Comment: http://lall.stanford.edu/svn/engr207c_2010_to_2011_autumn/data/norms_2008_10_07_01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Well, these notes are very brief. In reality, one first defines the calligraphic L $^p$ space consisting of Lebesgue measurable functions which satisfy $\|f\|_p=(\int\limits_{D}{|f|^p})^{1/p}<\infty$. Now this is still not a norm, because not all functions with this quantity being zero are identically zero functions - they can be nonzero on sets with measure 0. Therefore this space is partitioned into equivalence classes with respect to the equivalence relation "equal almost every where", i.e $f$ and $g$ are in one and the same equivalence class iff $f-g=0$ a.e, which is iff $\|f-g\|_p=0$. Then the resulting space of equivalence classes is denoted by $L^p$ (not calligraphic) and is normed using the same expression $\|f\|_p$ which now becomes a real norm, because only the zero element has a norm zero. To understand this better, I suggest that you read about equivalence relations and partitioning, as well as about seminorms. Maybe the book "Measure theory and integration" by Michael E. Taylor, Chapter 4 will help you. The construction of $L^p$ is informally summarized there.

Comment: It isn't so much the concept of equivalence relations and partitioning. I've had taken group theory and have at least a basic idea of what they are about. The problem might really be about how most notes hand wave the concept of function space, Normed vector space,  and the associated idea.

Comment: Then I can not help you anymore.